# move messages between ActiveMQ queues in Camel w/o deserializing

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm running Camel embedded in ActiveQM 5.11.1.  I have some Java serialized messages that I need to move between queues with a simple Camel route...

```
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:A"/>
        <to uri="activemq:B"/>
    </route>
```

as expected, I get this error...

> WARN | Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by:
>   [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - Failed to extract body due
>   to: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content.
>   Serializable class not available to broker. Reason:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.MyMessage. Message:
>   ActiveMQObjectMessage

I know this is because Camel/AMQ doesn't know about `MyMessage` and I can add it to AMQ's classpath to get around this...but that isn't an option in my case.

Instead, can I just tell Camel/AMQ to not try to deserialize it and just move it?  I tried the `jmsMessageType` options, but they didn't get around this error...

Comment: Try with mapJmsMessage=false

Comment: that Claus...I get this warning in the logs " WARN | Cannot determine specific JmsMessage type to use from body class. Will use generic JmsMessage. Body class: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage. If you want to send a POJO then your class might need to implement java.io.Serializable, or you can force a specific type by setting the jmsMessageType option on the JMS endpoint." but it did move the messages...

Comment: @Claus - add that as an answer and I'll give you full credit ;)

Comment: Ah to get rid of the warn you can try to set jmsMessageType=Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn of mapping from JMS to Camel Message using the `mapJmsMessage=false` option.

And then set `jmsMessageType=Object` so when sending to the queue, Camel will not try to guess the message type, but use object as configured, then the message is sent as-is.